# How to write recursive multiplication function in pyret

Tags: function, recursion, pyret

My programming languages class uses pyret. I've only really learned c++ so it's a little confusing for me right now. We were given a homework assignment regarding natural numbers. the "S()" just means successor of a natural number (which is just another natural number), so pretty much anything but zero. The following function is provided:

```
fun nat-plus(n :: Nat, m :: Nat) -> Nat:
  cases (Nat) n:
    |O => m
    |S(nn) => S(nat-plus(nn, m))
  end
```

This function just adds n and m. I think the main problem is that I'm not 100% sure how this function works but I have a bit of an idea.

The next step in the homework is to write a function that multiplies n and m using the nat-plus function above. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for writing this function?

Comment: Great question! I'm curious – what's the collaboration policy for your course? It's difficult to know how much your instructor wants you to get this kind of help (Which may be totally allowed! It's just not a common default) and I'd like to respect that before answering.

Comment: @jpolitz High-level discussion is allowed

Comment: I see. On reflection it’s a bit hard to do an answer justice on StackOverflow because a back-and-forth would be better. For example, the first question I want to ask is this — what examples of calling nat-plus have you tried in the interactions area? What do they tell you about nat-plus?